# how to achieve the below widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am not able to attach country code and country flag inside a Text field for phone number 
I am new to flutter so i need step by step instructions. thank you
I want same like in image

[image]

Comment: That's actually two controls put along and nothing else, so you can do it yourself as well otherwise i can help if you can't

Comment: I did not get the logic for doing so.

Comment: On left dropdown is used and alongside that textfield is used

Comment: yeah i knew that but i could  not do in coding

Comment: Try this [library](https://github.com/niinyarko/flutter-international-phone-input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: Card(
      child: Padding(
         padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
         child: Row(
           children: [
              Icon(Icons.flag),
              SizedBox(width: 5),
              Text("+91"),
              SizedBox(width: 20),
              Expanded(
                child: TextFormField(
                   decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: "Enter your mobile number",
            )
           ],
          ),
         ),
        ),
       )
```

and the end result is something like this:

[image: Flutter Card]

You can replace the Widget `Icon` for `Image` and use the correct flag.